# Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше сделать страницы в приложении?

Tags: android, android-fragment

1) В каком случае страницу(например Настроек) делать как фрагмент, а в каком как полноценную страницу(прим. Basic Activity)?
2) Как сделать сохранение данных в фрагменте или странице после переключения?
P.S. любые примеры приветствуются, спасибо)

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду под страницей? Activity?

Comment: да, например Basic Activity

Comment: Суть в чем... Я, например, вообще всегда использую только одну Activity, которая просто контролит фрагменты. А кто-то наоборот, вообще не использует фрагменты. Это дело вкуса, привычки и опыта. Попробуйте сейчас одним способом, потом - другим. Сами поймете, как Вам нравится больше

Comment: Спасибо вам, будем пробовать)

Comment: А еще не подскажите, как сохранить данные в фрагменте после переключения на другой фрагмент?

Comment: Тут способов много. Погуглите, в интернете много всего на этут тему

Comment: Если примитивные данные используй SharedPreferences или бд. В ином случае записуй в файл и читай потом.